# What is `servicehubd` in my notifications? Is it a virus or malware?

Tags: mac, virus, malware, notifications

I can't find much about this.  What is servicehubd? Is it bad for my computer?

[image]

Comment: "Is it bad for my computer?" - Nope

Comment: If you want to get rid of it then uninstall Avira

Comment: I didn't know it was Avira related.  Thanks!

Comment: Quick Google search determined that